# Getting error while building project "com.bea.util.jam.internal.javadoc.JavadocClassloadingException:"

Tags: build, ant, teamcity

I am getting error while trying to build a java project in TeamCity. The same project builds and excecutes well on my local. I recently pushed changes to this project on GitLab. This is my first time working with GitLab and TeamCity together. Other projects have no issues during build. I am unable to understand what is causing this error:

```
[15:58:54][Step 1/1] compile.earCommons (4s)
[15:58:54][compile.earCommons] echo
[15:58:54][compile.earCommons] echo
[15:58:54][compile.earCommons] wlcompile (4s)
[15:58:59][wlcompile] 
com.bea.util.jam.internal.javadoc.JavadocClassloadingException: An error 
has occurred while invoking javadoc to inspect your source
files.  This may be due to the fact that $JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar does
not seem to be in your system classloader.  One common case in which 
this happens is when using the 'ant' tool, which uses a special
context classloader to load classes from tools.jar.

This situation elicits what is believed to a javadoc bug in the initial
release of JDK 1.6.  Javadoc attempts to use its own context classloader
tools.jar but ignores one that may have already been set, which leads
to some classes being loaded into two different classloaders.  The
telltale sign of this problem is a javadoc error message saying that
'languageVersion() must return LanguageVersion - you might see this
message in your process' output.

This will hopefully be fixed in a later release of JDK 1.6; if a new
version of 1.6 has become available, you might be able to solve this
by simply upgrading to the latest JDK.

Alternatively, you can work around it by simply including 
$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar in the java -classpath
parameter.  If you are running ant, you will need to modify the standard
ant script to include tools.jar in the -classpath.
[15:58:59][Step 1/1] Process exited with code 1
[15:58:59][Step 1/1] Ant output
[15:59:10][Step 1/1] Process exited with code 1 (Step: Ant)
[15:58:59][Step 1/1] Step Ant failed
```

****Update****

```
Build Step: Ant
Step 1:
Runner type: Ant (Runner for Ant build.xml files)
Execute:  If all previous steps finished successfully
build.xml file: \ant\build.xml
Working directory: same as checkout directory
Targets: none specified
Ant home path: C:\apache-ant-1.7.0
Additional Ant command line parameters: -lib c:\WebLogic\12.1.2\wlserver\server\lib\javaee.jar;c:\WebLogic\12.1.2\wlserver\server\lib\weblogic.jar;c:\WebLogic\12.1.2\wlserver\server\lib\webservices.jar
JDK home path: c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80
JVM command line parameters: not specified
Reduce test failure feedback time: OFF
Java code coverage: disabled
Docker Settings
Docker Image: unset
```

I'll appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: check $JAVA_HOME environment var, and if $JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar exists. probably you have jre instead of jdk

Comment: If the problem is environment variable or jdk/jre, how will other projects compile? Other projects are compiling fine, only problem is with one particular project.

Comment: @Ram add to question body your build step please

Comment: Updated with Build Steps

Comment: So, I found there was character encoding issue with one of the files that prevented compiler from loading the java classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found there was character encoding issue with one of the files that prevented compiler from loading the java classes. Once that was fixed, the build worked fine.